# Android how take full screen with more LinearLayout orientation horizontal

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

i'm trying to do a school day and i use multiple linearLayout with days and hours.
With the `layout_weight` i can set the space for every elements inside the single `LinearLayout`.
But my problem is how can i set the `layout_weight`for the `LinearLayout` because they are set with orientation horizontal and they don't take the entire screen.
It's like a table but i use LinearLayout because i need to create only rows.

This is the xml of the Activity

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.ddz.diarioscolastico.OrarioActivityProva">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Lun"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
       />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Mar"
        android:id="@+id/textView" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Mer"
        android:id="@+id/textView3" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Gio"
        android:id="@+id/textView4" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Ven"
        android:id="@+id/textView5" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Sab"
        android:id="@+id/textView6" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="1"
        android:id="@+id/textView7" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout3">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="2"
        android:id="@+id/textView8" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout3"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout4">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="3"
        android:id="@+id/textView9" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout4"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout6">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="4"
            android:id="@+id/textView10" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout6"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout5">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="5"
        android:id="@+id/textView11" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout5"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout7">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="6"
        android:id="@+id/textView12" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout7"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout8">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="7"
        android:id="@+id/textView13" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout8"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="8"
        android:id="@+id/textView14" />
</LinearLayout>
```

As you can see if i set the `android:layout_height="match_parent"` yes all `LinearLayout` take full screen but only the first is visible, i wanna divide the screen for all.

Comment: `layout_weight` is for LinearLayouts. Change your root element to a LinearLayout.

Comment: @karaokyo thank you, now i put all the `LinearLayout` inside another `LinearLayout` with orientation vertical and now work!
Can i use the weight for a `TableLayout` for the `View` inside to `TableRow` ??
Thank you again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using Layout Weight is a little bit tricky task.
Suppose you want to show three buttons  horizontally which share equal width in a linear layout. Then the xml code should be like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="3"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <Button 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button 1"
        />
    <Button 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button 1"
        />
    <Button 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button 1"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

As you can see,In the parent LinearLayout i used weightSum as 3 and in each child button i set the width to 0dp and weight to 1 and there are three buttons so it will share equal width.

By the way the root parent (RelativeLayout) is not closed in your given layout.

**EDIT:2**

As you said here is the code divide each LinearLayout equally with layout_weight

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="3"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="#00FF00"
        >

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="#FF0000"
        >

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="#0000FF"
        >

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**OUTPUT :** 
[image: OutPut]

Comment: I forget to copy it! Thanks for your answere, but i need to divide the screen for all LinearLayout vertically.
If i put all the LinearLayout inside another LinearLayout i can set the weight of the others.

Comment: Absolutely you could be able to set the child LinearLayout with weight.

Comment: Yes, it's exacly what i mean and what i need. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to replace your LinearLayout with a TableRow or use a GridLayout ?  GridLayout requires API 14 but lower API can be use with the support library.